# How can I make the display of a line in my command-line java program change without displaying a new line?

Tags: java, command-line

I'm making a java command line program.

How can I change the contents of a line I've already displayed?

So, for example I could display:

Status: 0%
Status: 2%
...
Status: 50%

Except, rather than continuing to push down each new line, I simply change the contents of the existing line, so the % done changes in place.

I've seen some console programs do this before, so how can I do it in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, you can output a carriage return (`\r`) rather than a newline (`\n`). This depends on the terminal supporting it, which most do. `\r` moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line.

EDIT: Obviously, when doing this, use `System.out.print` rather than `System.out.println` (or just generally use the plain, not `ln`, form of the output method you're using) -- since the `ln` suffix means that your text is automatically followed with a newline.

Example:

```
for (n = 10000; n < 10010; ++n) {
    System.out.print(String.valueOf(n) + "\r");
}
System.out.println("Done");
```

When this finishes, you'll probably have this on your console screen:

```
Done0
```

...since "Done" is shorter than the longest previous thing you output, and so didn't completely overwrite it (hence the 0 at the end, left over from "10010").  So the lesson is:  Keep track of the longest thing you write and overwrite it with spaces.

Comment: Will this not append the output to the previously outputted "print"?

Comment: Some code I know uses `\b` to "backspace out" the bits to replace, rather than replacing the whole line with `\r`.

Comment: @Isharyan: `\r` puts the cursor at the start of the line ("for most terminals"), so anything you append after it will appear at the start of the line.

Comment: @lsharyan: Sorry, I should have said what Chris said in the answer. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: if the next line to come up is physically less spaces than the previous, how do I ensure I don't have any hanging remnants of the last line?  Append a bunch of spaces or?

Comment: @lsharyan: Yup, included a note about that in my edit just now in fact.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **[this example](http://luka.tnode.com/blog/2007/07/java-console-progress-bar)**.

Working code:

```
public class progress {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {    
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(30);
            System.out.print("\rSTATUS: "+i+" % " );
        }   
    }
}
```

Tip: For more Google - java console progress bar

Comment: I would add that JLine works very well for this sort of stuff